# parse error on vinyl source stream on gulp browserify babelify project

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

I am getting a rather unrevealing parser error while trying to execute a source stream on a gulp/babelify/browserify project. The error is:

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
Error: app.js.map: error: couldn't process source due to parse error
Unexpected token (1:10)
```

My gulp configuration is the following:

```
var path = require('path');

var gulp = require('gulp');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

browserify({
            //cache: {},
            //packageCache: {},
          //  fullPaths: true,
            debug: true,
            entries: options.src + '/app/app.js',
            paths: ['./src'],
            extensions: [' ', 'js']

        })
    // .add(require.resolve('babel-polyfill'))
        .transform(babelify.configure({
            "presets": ["es2015"],
            ignore: [
                '/bower_components',
                '/node_modules'
            ]
        }))
        .bundle()
        //  .on('error', util.log.bind(util, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write('./', {sourceRoot: './js'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/serve/app'))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe($.replace('__API_URL__', process.env['API_URL'] || 'http://devint.api.com'));
```

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: what is on line 10 of `app.js`?

Comment: Actually the error corresponds to line 1 and column 10 of app.js.map. Column 10 corresponds to the 'sources' key in the map.

Comment: Ah yes, misread that. What version of `ng-annotate` are you using?

Comment: Its gulp-ng-annotate version 1.1.0.

Comment: try piping through `ngAnnotate` before `uglify`

Comment: I dont think it even gets as far as annotate because the process breaks on stream or in this case 'source'. That is why if you notice the stack it throws an exception on stream.js.

Comment: That just means the error is happening in a stream, everything in gulp is a stream

Comment: Cool, that fixed the error. You can add it as an answer and ill accept it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe through `ngAnnotate()` before your `uglify()`.